# Special name and the general solution method for the given integral

Tags: integration

I wonder whether the integral

$$
I = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{e^{i\vec{p} \cdot \vec{x} }}{\vec{p}^2+m^2},
$$

has a special name or not and besides I am also interested in the general method (if there is one) that explains how to approach these type of integrals. I will be glad if anyone can help.

Comment: you missed to write on which variable it depends - on d, p or m? or altogether

Comment: polar coordinates + residuetheorem should do the job

Comment: @Lady Melina I didn't understand what you mean exactly. The integral is taken over $p$ and all the other parameters seen inside the integral sign are independent from each other.